# ORA-00933: oracle 8i

Tags: sql, join, oracle8i

I want to use join in Oracle 8i. I have my query as below. 
I have this query of getting data from two tables using an `join`, but I get the error `SQL command not properly ended`.

```
    private List<StamfordProdRelease> GetStamfordProdReleases()
    {
        List<StamfordProdRelease> list = null;

        string srtQry = "SELECT NVL(NULL, 0) ID," +
        "                DLOG.RELEASEID AS RELEASE_BUILD," +
        "                TRUNC (DLOGDET.DEPLOYDATE) AS PROD_DEPLOY_DATE," +
        "                DLOGDET.DEPLOYREQUEST AS BAAR_RFD," +
        "                DLOG.FILENAMEEXT_VC AS SCRIPT_NAME," +
        "                DLOG.VERSION," +
        "                DLOG.REQUEST," +
        "                DLOG.NOTE AS COMMENTS" +
        "                FROM ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOGDETAIL DLOGDET" +
        "                JOIN ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOG DLOG ON DLOG.LOGNO = DLOGDET.LOGNO;";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Globals.Constants.AppConnectionStringReadOnly))
        {
            using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(srtQry, conn))
            {
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
                conn.Open();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    list = ConvertToStamfordProdRelease(dt).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

My target is to insert records into a table.

Comment: remove ";" from query

Comment: Why un-accept answer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't combine the, strings put all in one.

Answer (score 0):

Keep everything in one set of `"` and also you only need a single `;` to end the SQL query outside of the double quotes.

```
    private List<StamfordProdRelease> GetStamfordProdReleases()
    {
        List<StamfordProdRelease> list = null;

        string srtQry = "SELECT NVL(NULL, 0) ID, 
DLOG.RELEASEID AS RELEASE_BUILD, 
TRUNC (DLOGDET.DEPLOYDATE) AS PROD_DEPLOY_DATE, 
DLOGDET.DEPLOYREQUEST AS BAAR_RFD, 
DLOG.FILENAMEEXT_VC AS SCRIPT_NAME, 
DLOG.VERSION, 
DLOG.REQUEST, 
DLOG.NOTE AS COMMENTS 
FROM ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOGDETAIL DLOGDET 
JOIN ADM_DEPLOYMENTLOG DLOG ON DLOG.LOGNO = DLOGDET.LOGNO";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Globals.Constants.AppConnectionStringReadOnly))
        {
            using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(srtQry, conn))
            {
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
                conn.Open();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    list = ConvertToStamfordProdRelease(dt).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 8i did not support standard ANSI SQL `JOIN` syntax.

That feature was introduced in Oracle 9i Release 2 (aka Oracle 9.2)

[Quote from the chapter "What's New in SQL Reference"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/wnsql.htm#970381)

> SELECT [...] has new ANSI-compliant join syntax.